# Multiple timer Task on same service conflicting and misbehaving

Tags: android, service, timer, timertask

Since i have started using two timer task on same service it started misbehaving.

As i am calling api in both timer task 1 is calling api after 30 seconds and another timertask is calling and api after 5 minutes. now they are misbehaving in the way that some times timer task which call api after 5 minutes  started calling an api at any timer instead of after 5 minutes. Some times it hits an api 10-15 times  between 5 minutes and some timer it hits an api once in after 20-25 minutes.

Here is my code of timer task

```
Timer timer, timer_update_current_position;
    if (timer == null) {

            timer = new Timer();
            mytimer Mytimer = new mytimer();

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Mytimer, 300000, 300000);

        }

        if (timer_update_current_position == null) {

            timer_update_current_position = new Timer();
            TimerCurrentPos timerCurrentPos = new TimerCurrentPos();

            timer_update_current_position.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerCurrentPos,
                    30000, 30000);

        }
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue because its adding data in bult on my server.

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to use `Timer` on Android.  `Timer` is a heavyweight solution that introduces the complication of multithreading where it usually isn't needed.  Use `Handler#postDelayed(...)` instead.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede will it be running thread after particular period of time continously ..??

Comment: Yes you can get the same behavior as `scheduleAtFixedRate` using handler conjunction with timer and thread

Comment: @Prasad  are you sure  that handle doesn't gonna misbehave like timer task as i have mentioned in the question..actually main prob is that.

Comment: @Edward I was replying your comment ("will it be running thread after particular period of time continously?")